# Codeigniter : Session_id is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ip-address

I have a probleme in PHP Codeigniter, I'm trying to get the sessions Id, but it returns an empty string,

this is my code (ControllerTest.php):

```
class ControllerTest extends CI_Controller
{   
    public function test(){
        echo "session: ".$this->session->userdata('session_id');
    }
}
```

And in autoload.php i have this :

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

and in the output, i only get this :
`session:`

**EDIT :**

And when I print the session `print_r($this->session->userdata);` i get this:

`Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1441821744 )`

And if i try ro access the ip_address like this :

`$this->session->userdata('ip_address');`

It also returns an empty string

Comment: Did you include session_start();?

Comment: I think in codeigniter we don't have to use session_start, all we need to do is load session library

Comment: in this article [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)
they say that : 
`To initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the $this->load->library() method`

Comment: print all session, to see if you having something on that: `print_r($this->session->userdata);` Edit your question with this printing.

Comment: looking for the session id? if you're using CI3, you should use $this->session->session_id. they changed the session lib a lot from V2 to V3.

Comment: in the constructor you must put the library to load, in this case $this->load->library('session'); then call it by $this->session->userdata

Comment: @ErmanBelegu I edited  my QST

Comment: @avenda as i said in the qst, the session is autoloaded

Comment: @JoséTrindade it works for Session_id, and it doesn't work for ip_address, i tried this $this->session->ip_address but it returns an empty string, can u show me please how to get the ip_address.
Thx

Comment: try using $this->session->all_userdata('session_id') and $this->session->all_userdata('ip_address')

Comment: according to the documentation, you should use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the user ip. you can also use session_id() to access session id. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata

Comment: @JoséTrindade Thank You ^^ ur answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this

   $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
2. Try this,

   $this->session->all_userdata();

And returns an associative array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623
)
```